# Factorial Analysis return to original atributes

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, k-means, sklearn-pandas, dimensionality-reduction

A little explanation first im working on a unsupervied clustering model using factorial analysis and KMeans.

I have a dataframe with 10 columns where i performed a dimensionality reduction to n=3 using factorial analysis, after that i used KMeans to determine 4 clusters. Using the method `estimator.cluster_centers_` i got the center coordinates of every cluster.

```
fa = FactorAnalysis(n_components=3) 
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_f = scaler.fit_transform(df)
X_f = fa.fit_transform(X_f)

estimator = KMeans(n_clusters=4, n_init=2, init="random", random_state=1)
estimator.fit(X_f)
centers = estimator.cluster_centers_
```

Here is my question, i need to determine the original atributes (in the 10 columns dataframe) of every center point of the clusters given by KMeans, how can i proceed?.

Since the center points are not part of X_f, i dont know how to continue.

Comment: Since your code works, this isn't really a programming question so I think you should move this question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Also, check this question there out: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302706/how-to-reverse-factor-analysis-fa-and-reconstruct-original-variables

Comment: Separate issue: you aren't showing the actual application of the factor analysis, which is really the thing you're asking about.